# Jest testing a property update inside a DOM chain

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dom, jestjs

I am trying to determine a way to test if a property value has been updated from a DOM chain.

Currently I have a DOM function mock that returns an object which I can use for testing chained functions. However how would I test if the `textContent` property value updated?

*index.js*

```js
const setText = (text) => {
  document.getElementById('id').textContent = text;
};
```

*index.spec.js*

```js
const mockListener = jest.fn();
jest.spyOn(document, 'getElementById').mockImplementation(() => ({
  addEventListener: mockListener,
  textContent: '',
}));

it('Should set text content', () => {
  setText('test');
  expect(document.getElementById).toHaveBeenCalledWith('id');
  // ? Trying to determine how to target to test the update
  expect(document.getElementById().textContent).toBe('test');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `mockImplementation` would be called a second time, you'll be receiving a distinct object each time. You'll want to pull out the returned object into a variable and have the same object returned each time:

```
it('Should set text content', () => {
  const mockDomObject = {
    addEventListener: jest.fn(),
    textContent: '',
  }
  jest.spyOn(document, 'getElementById').mockImplementation(() => mockDomObject);

  setText('test');

  expect(document.getElementById).toHaveBeenCalledWith('id');
  expect(mockDomObject.textContent).toBe('test');
});
```

Alternately if you still want the setup to remain shared, you can use `document.getElementById.mock.results[0].value` to access the same DOM object that was returned for the unit under test.

```
setText('test');

expect(document.getElementById).toHaveBeenCalledWith('id');
const domObject = document.getElementById.mock.results[0].value;
expect(domObject.textContent).toBe('test');
```

Comment: This is incredible. Thank you so much for the explanation and examples!